# Load SPI class with URLClassLoader rise ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I did some research, But due to complexity of this situation, Not working for me.

> [Child first class loader and Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103197/child-first-class-loader-and-service-provider-interface-spi)

Like flink or tomcat, My application run as framework with platform and system classloader.
Framework load plugin as module and plugin may depend some lib, so make this define:

```
plugin/plugin-demo.jar
depend/plugin-demo/depend-1.jar
depend/plugin-demo/depend-2.jar
```

framework will create two classloader like this:

```java
URLClassLoader dependClassloader = new URLClassLoader({URI-TO-depend-jars}, currentThreadClassLoader);
URLClassLoader pluginClassloader = new URLClassLoader({URI-TO-plugin-jar},dependClassloader);
```

With an HelloWorld demo this is working file ( and at first I NOT set systemClassloader as parent).

But with JDBC driver `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` which using SPI goes into trouble:

Even I manual register driver:

```java
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", true, pluginClassloader);
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver driver = (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
```

This working fine, But after that:

```java
DriverManager.getConnection(this.hostName, this.userName, this.password)
```

will rise

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:440)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 7 more
```

Or:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/furryblack
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
```

I try to print all driver:

```java
Enumeration<java.sql.Driver> driverEnumeration = DriverManager.getDrivers();
while (driverEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    java.sql.Driver driver = driverEnumeration.nextElement();
    System.out.println(driver);
}
```

And there is no driver registered.

So, Question is: why NoClassDefFoundError ?

I have some guess: DriverManager run in systemclassloader but driver load in my classloader parent won't search in children, So I set currentThreadClassLoader as parent but still rise exception.

## Update 1:

URI-TO-depend-jars is Array of File.toURI().toURL().
This design working fine with demo, So I think it should be correct.

And with debug, The ClassLoader parent chain is
`ModuleLoader -> DependLoader`
And with systemclassloader is
`ModuleLoader -> DependLoader -> BuiltinAppClassLoader -> PlatformClassLoader -> JDKInternalLoader`

[image: This is working fine, SpecialDepend loaded]

This is the full code:

Interface in jar 1:

```java
public interface AbstractComponent {
    void handle();
}
```

Plugin in jar2 (depend jar3 in pom.xml):

```java
public class Component implements AbstractComponent {

    @Override
    public void handle() {
        System.out.println("This is component handle");
        SpecialDepend.tool();
    }
}
```

Depend in jar3:

```java
public class SpecialDepend {

    public static void tool() {
        System.out.println("This is tool");
    }
}
```

Main in jar1:

```java
@Test
public void test() {

    String path = "D:\\Server\\Classloader";

    File libFile = Paths.get(path, "lib", "lib.jar").toFile();
    File modFile = Paths.get(path, "mod", "mod.jar").toFile();

    URLClassLoader libLoader;
    try {
        URL url;
        url = libFile.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = {url};
        libLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

    URLClassLoader modLoader;
    try {
        URL url;
        url = modFile.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = {url};
        modLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, libLoader);
    } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("demo.Component", true, modLoader);
        if (AbstractComponent.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            AbstractComponent instance = (AbstractComponent) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            instance.handle();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
This is component handle
This is tool
```

This is working perfect.

## Update 2:

[image]

I try to print more debug and some unnecessary code, Then I found, The Driver class can be found and instancelized, But the `DriverManager.registerDriver` didn't register it.

So the question become: Why DriverManager can't register driver load from sub classloader?

## Update3

contextClassLoader is get from `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` But inject by framework with `currentThread.setContextClassLoader(exclusiveClassLoader);`

As double check I print the hashcode, Its same.

And I debug into DriverManager, Its was registered the driver into internal List but after that, getDrivers will got nothing.

[image: registeredDrivers has the registered element]
[image: getDrivers got no driver]

Comment: What is the actual value of `{URI-TO-PLUGIN-JAR}`?  This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/738422/15273968

Comment: On Update 2, can you see what class loader is loading the DriverManager? And this `contextClassLoader` reference is it a product of `java.lang.Thread#getContextClassLoader()` from current thread?

Comment: @SaleemKhair I update with updated3, I found something strange , As far as I know about java, Loaded class from another classloader can still working even it's URLClassLoader closed.

Comment: A class loader looks for class in its parent first, and the parent delegates to its parent and so on, so class loaders that are siblings cannot see eachothers classes, also the `DriverManager#getDrivers()` internally validate if the caller classloader can load the class using `DriverManager#isDriverAllowed(Driver, ClassLoader)` so even if Driver is pupulated in the registration, it still might not register, that's why you get an empty list.

Comment: That solve my question, I debug into DriverManager, getDriver will check by getCaller and caller's Classloader. I need do some work with classloader inherit tree but that will off topic, Appreciate for that hint! Consider write an answer? @SaleemKhair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassLoader` looks for classes in its parent first, and the parent delegates to its parent and so on. With that said, ClassLoaders that are siblings cannot see eachothers classes.

Also the method `DriverManager#getDrivers()` internally validates if the caller ClassLoader can load the class with `DriverManager#isDriverAllowed(Driver, ClassLoader)`.
this means that even if your `Driver` is added to the registration list, it is only added as an instance of `DriverInfo`, this means that it would only be loaded on demand (Lazy), and still might not register when loading is attempted, that's why you get an empty list.